# Interactive Python Mac OS X help()

Tags: python, macos, terminal

When I run Python interactively in Terminal and call

```
help(print)
```

I get the help information, but then Python seems to get stuck.  At the end of the help information is the following, which is greyed out:

`(END)`

At this point, I have to exit the interactive python because it no longer responds to anything else.  Does anyone know how to continue in interactive Python or is this just a "feature" of interactive Python.

OS X 10.11.5

Python 3.4.4 or Python 3.5

Comment: Press ``q`` to quit

Answer (score 4):

`help()` prints its output using a pager, so that if the output is longer than a screenful it will pause at each screen end and let you tell it to continue. And at the end it prints `(END)`, and it's waiting for you to tell it what to do. Type <kbd>q</kbd> to exit from the pager. And type <kbd>h</kbd> to see all the other options you have at the prompt.